# odoo cant create access record for res.users

Tags: security, odoo, odoo-8

I want the sale group to have acces to write to the res.users model, but cant get the **ir.model.acces.csv** processed. The corresponding row is like this:

```
access_base_res_users_sales_manager,    res_users_sales_manager,    model_res_users, base.group_sale_manager,   1,  1,  0,  0
```

The error message says:

```
Exception: Module loading <my_module_name> failed: file <my_module_name>/security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
Line 10 : Kein passender Datensatz f\xfcr Externe ID 'model_res_users' in Feld 'Object' gefunden
```

The last line translates to:

```
Found no corresponding data record for external ID 'model_res_users' in field 'Object'
```

I tried it with the model entry `'model_base_res_users'`, but with the same effect. Whats wrong?

Comment: have you a "base" module added to a "depends" list in __openerp__.py manifest ?

Comment: also did you extend the `res.users` in your custom module?

Comment: yes I added the `base` module. And I don't extend the `res.users` model in my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because model `res.users` belongs to `base` module, which is not your current module, you have to specify module prefix. Like this:

`access_base_res_users_sales_manager, res_users_sales_manager, base.model_res_users, base.group_sale_manager, 1, 1, 0, 0`